# Spotify API - Find facebook users

Tags: facebook, spotify

Is it possible to use the Spotify JavaScript API to determine if an (authenticated) FaceBook user also uses Spotify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly. However, if you check their `listens` on Open Graph, you'll be able to see if they're actively sharing their listens to Facebook. However, it's certainly possible to be connected to Facebook and not share your listens.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at listens on Facebook open graph